# Am I able to remove a reference to a file in SQLite to resolve an error?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, flutter

I'm using the sqflite library for Flutter, and when I try to open a contacts2.db file from the emulator, I get the following error:

> E/SQLiteLog(15584): (14) cannot open file at line 34308 of
>   [605907e73a] E/SQLiteLog(15584): (14) os_unix.c:34308: (13)
>   open(/sdcard/contacts2copy.db-shm) -  E/SQLiteLog(15584): (14) unable
>   to open database file E/flutter (15584):
>   [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled
>   exception: E/flutter (15584): DatabaseException(open_failed
>   /sdcard/contacts2copy.db)

Without this line, I'm almost sure the database would open fine. 
The same database opens without issue in sqlite3 on my computer. Also, another contacts2.db file opens fine. Is there a way to ignore or remove this reference?